# How does C retrieve the address of a row for a 2d array

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, pointer-arithmetic

Can someone explain to me how C retrieves the correct memory address for a row when you only use one subscript to access a 2d array?

Example -

```
int array2D[2][2] = {1,2,3,4};
printf ( "starting address of row2 = %p" , array2D[1]);
```

I understand that when subscripting in C that what is actually going on is pointer addition so for a 1d array the array name points to element 0. In this case if I had wanted element 1 the compiler would take the starting address (say 4000) and add 4 to it (assuming a 4 bit int) so that what is returned is the item at memory address 4004.

My understanding is that when you populate a 2d array, as in my example, they are allocated sequentially so I would have

1 2
3 4
at addresses

4000 4004

4008 4012

So how does C work out that in this case array2D[1] should point to 4008 and not 4004? Does it run a sizeof() operator or have I misunderstood a fundamental here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your example is a 1 Dimensional array.

Comment: No, you didn't: see Keith Randall's answer for the correct syntax

Comment: @Useless, yes he did. The inner braces are optional if you specify a complete array type.

Comment: Interesting, I never knew that!  I don't think it's as readable, but still good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C knows how long each row is, so it does the multiplication to find the row.

```
int x[][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
```

then `&x[1][0]` is `&x[0][0]` plus `3 * sizeof(int)`.

That's why in a multidimensional C array declaration, all but the first dimension must be specified.

Comment: Ah excellent, thanks for that Keith. Blindingly obvious when it's explained :)

Comment: @Keith Randall: interesting answer, but how does C know the length of each row? Isn't x in this case just a pointer to a pointer to integer? Where is the "row size" information stored?

Comment: @curvature: C knows the length of each row from the declaration.  Try not putting the `3` there and see what happens (hint: compiler error).  The row size is not stored anywhere at run time (except coded in the generated code).  `x` is not a pointer to a pointer to an integer, it is a pointer to an array of integers (in my example, 6 of them).  There are no pointers within the array (unlike, e.g. Java, so you can't do `x[0]=...`).

Comment: I see, I understand it now. Now it makes sense why you need to explicitly define the size of the rows. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer arithmetic depends on the type of the element being pointed to.  Given a pointer `p` to type `T`, `p + 1` points to the next *element* of type `T`, not necessarily the next byte following `p`.  If `T` is `char`, then `p + 1` points to the next `char` object after `p`, which starts at the byte immediately following `p`; if `T` is `char [10]`, then `p + 1` points to the next *10-element array of `char`* after `p`, which starts at the 10th byte following `p`.

The type of the *expression* `array2d` in is "2-element array of 2-element array of `int`", which "decays" to type "pointer to 2-element array of `int`", or `int (*)[2]`<sup>1</sup>.  Thus the expression `array2d[1]` is interpreted as `*(array2d + 1)`.  Since `array2d` points to an object of type `int [2]`, `array2d + 1` points to the next 2-element array of `int` following `array2d`, which is `2 * sizeof int` bytes away from `array2d`.

---

<sup>1.  Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and its value will be the address of the first element in the array.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a bit long-winded, but bear with me still.

Array subscription is just a shorthand: `(p[N])` equals `(*(p + N))` in all contexts for pointer types (both are invalid expressions for `void*`, though).

Now, if `p` is an array type, it would decay to a pointer type in an expression like `(*(p + N))`; an `int[2][2]` would decay into a pointer of type `(*)[2]` (i.e. a pointer to an `int[2]`).

Pointer arithmetic takes types into account; we need to convert things to `char*` to visualize what the compiler does to us:

```
T *p;
p[N] equals *(p + N) equals *(T*)((unsigned char*)p + N * sizeof *p)
```

Now, if `T` were an `int[2]` (to equal the situation we described above), then `sizeof *p` would be `sizeof(int[2])`, i.e. `2 * sizeof(int)`.

This is how subscription works in so-called multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

sizeof(array2D[1]) == 8;
if array2D address is 4000;
so array2D[1] address is 4000+sizeof(array2D[1]) == 4000+8;